# Image Recognition for Android/iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, objective-c

I'm looking at developing an app that could benefit from having a image recognition system. I've seen this sort of thing in iPhone and Android apps. Take a picture of a book and the app takes you to Amazon where you can find that book. I'm not looking for general image recognition, but more the ability to pick a single image out of a library of about 10k images.

Any ideas of what services are available for this sort of thing?

Comment: Image recognition is a huge subfield of Computer Vision, it would help to know more about the type of problem you intend to solve with recognition before any exact algorithm recommendations could be made (many of the mature and highly-effective comptuer vision techniques solve problems in a somewhat specific domain).

Comment: What I'm actually looking for is the ability to take images of playing cards from popular trading card games, like Magic the Gathering, and pull up the data on the card, or perhaps the price from a database. I'd like the ability for users to use the cell phone camera to take a image of the card, and then pull that card's data out of the database.

So all the images are going to be 2D. And the dataset is going to be fairly small, around 10k options or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Goggles](http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/#landmark) does something similar to Amazon Remembers. It uses OCR if text can be identified and they want to use it with the similar image search from Google Images. I think they generate some kind of hash for an image with the feature that if the images are similar the images are similar to.

My best guess would be try to start with the character recognition and do a text search for the title of your card. This means your user has to make a very clear image maybe even in a specific position. But for a first application this would be great already. As somebody playing magic I would buy the tool for trading and cataloging my cards.

Comment: That's a great idea...I didn't think of the OCR recognition part of it. That would certainly simplify things and allow the user to not have to have the entire card in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, while short of getting an actual Amazon employee to tell you there is no way to confirm this, I am fairly certain that the Amazon Remembers feature you refer to is actually the work of crowd sourcing- using lots of people combing through data to make it appear like a computer is doing it. I think they may actually be using there own [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) system.

Edit: Also, I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279768/ocr-playing-cards) that might interest you. It is specifically for playing cards, but some of the answers (such as the machine learning example) can be modified to be more helpful for what you want to do with magic cards.

Comment: Well considering that the entire process takes less than 10 sec...I doubt this is it. By the time the image is transmitted to Amazon, and the new page is sent back, we're looking at about 1-2sec in processing time, that'd have to be one fast Turk.

Comment: If you take a picture of something with a clear title on it (which can be identified evewn by a human in almost no time), yes it only takes 10 secs. Tried taking a picture of a random item, it takes much longer. Also, google Amazon Remembers and Mechanical Turk, you will find hits where people have tested the system and confirmed that at least some of the time they are using the Mechanical Turk system. Amazon has never said how they do Amazon Remembers, so it is a guess. My only point is that at least part of what amazon remembers does is faked, so they may not be the best example.